# How to store values in database when gender radio button checked

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows application, I have three radio buttons: male, female and others.
When I checked male radio button, I assigned 1 value to variable and after I insert that value to sql table. But I used checked changed event. I am getting system format exception. I used below code please help me on this.

```
if (rbmale.Checked)
{
    genders = 1;

}
else  if (rbfemale.Checked)
{
    genders = 2;

}
else if(rbothers.Checked)
{

    genders = 3;
}

private void rbmale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)
        genders = Convert.ToInt32(((RadioButton)sender).Text.ToString());
}

private void rbfemale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)
        genders = Convert.ToInt32(((RadioButton)sender).Text.ToString());
}

private void rbothers_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((RadioButton)sender).Checked == true)
        genders = Convert.ToInt32(((RadioButton)sender).Text.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why would a radiobutton have a text property?   Radio buttons are Boolean (on or off).    rbmale_CheckedChanged can only be called by the rbmail radio button, so just set genders = 1 (etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have check changed event for every radio, which means what is it so just set it 
Second where is below code gets executed ? If this gets executed on some submit click then this code more than enough

```
if (rbmale.Checked)
        {
            genders = 1;

        }
        else  if (rbfemale.Checked)
        {
            genders = 2;

        }
    else if(rbothers.Checked)
        {

            genders = 3;
        }
```

As these are radio buttons at a time only one is executed so you may not need check changed because if one is check remaining gets unchecked, but if you what check changed the code you wrote seems like you are trying to achieve all check changes in single event if that's the case, put the numbers in the tag property of radio button and assign single event to all radio buttons

```
private void rbgender_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton clicked = (RadioButton)sender;
        if(clicked.Checked)
           genders = Convert.ToInt32(clicked.Tag);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a system format exception because you are converting the text of the radiobutton to an integer. I'd assume the three radiobutton texts are: "Male", "Female", "Other" - which cannot convert to integer.